# What method uses the least memory to generate a range of numbers as a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list

When I run the following code to generate a list made of a range of numbers from 0 till 999 999 999. It raises a `MemoryError`. What other way can I use to generate the same list but wont use up that much memory?

```py
# Generate list
numbers = list(range(0,999999999))

# Add leading zeros
numbers = [str(x).zfill(9) for x in numbers]
```

Comment: It's not just the creation of the list that takes up so much memory. No matter how you create it, storing 1 billion strings in memory is going to fail.

Comment: You could write them to a file instead.

Comment: If you don't need a concrete list of numbers, use e.g. a generator expression instead. In other words, what do you need the list for?

Comment: Do you need everything beforehand? Seems like it would be pretty straightforward to generate only those values that you need in the downstream code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a generator:

```
def generator(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield str(i).zfill(9)
        i += 1
```

Usage:

```
for i in generator(5):
    print(i)
```

Or, to create a list:

```
[i for i in generator(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator:

```
numbers = (str(i).zfill(9) for i in range(999999999))
```

Comment: This doesn't generate a list.

Comment: Where is the `x` coming from?  Should it be `i` instead?  And this is only a `generator expression` not a list. as earlier comment pointed out/\.